# Pattern matching in scala on Seq[Any]

Tags: scala

I am not a scala expert but I would like to avoid use of asInstanceOf and replace that with pattern matching for sequences. Following snipped gives me an error `non-variable type argument`

```
val seq : Seq[Any] = getSeq();

val rec = seq match {
      case rec: Seq[Record[Key, Value]] => rec
      case other => throw new Exception(s"Expected a Seq[Record[Key, Value]]")
}
```

I have following code with `asInstanceOf` which works, but would like to replace it:

```
val values = seq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Record[Key, Vrade]]].map(_.value)
```

Comment: Avoid having a `Seq[Any]` in the first place, that check is not really easy to do and in general means a bad design.

Comment: How would fix that? Can you write the code so I better understand. Note, get getSeq() method is generic and return Seq[Any].

Comment: It means that you probably shouldn't be calling that method, or not using that library. What is the point of a strong type system it is going to be used like **Python**.

Comment: Now, if really need to call that method and all you have is a `Seq[Any]` then all you could do is something `val records: Seq[Record[Any, Any] = seq.collect { case rec: Record[_, _] => rec }` if you also need to check the types inside `Record` you would need to use something more complex and unsafer like a **TypeTag**, good luck with that.

Comment: This won't work with `asInstanceOf` either, it compiles but doesn't do what you want.

Comment: With `asInstanceOf` it works but I need to replace that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the elements to a new list with a type Seq[Record[Key, Vrade]]. So instead of matching the whole sequence, you match on the elements within the list.

It would be something like:

```
val values = seq.map {
    case x: Record[Key, Vrade]] => Some(x);
    case _ => None;
};
```

And then afterwards you can flatten it, or flatmap it to begin with, if you have the variable as List instead og Seq